# "Cделано" vs "де́лается" vs "де́лаемо"

Tags: перевод

Which one would you use to say "it is being done/ it is done well, poorly, etc" and for the past, would you use сделано or было сделано?  would they mean different things? i'm getting confused about passive participles and correct aspect.

Answer (score 3):

For "it is done well / poorly" you should just say "сделано хорошо / плохо". Basically for "done" as a verb you should just use "сделано" (in some contexts "готово" would be a better word, but this is not your case). "Было сделано" is actually "had been done", like in phrase "на этом пути было сделано много ошибок".

"Сделано" is a participle that can be used as a standalone word, like "сказано - сделано!" (it's said and it's done). "Было сделано" is about concrete act that had been performed/fullfilled.

"Делается" is used for describing action that is ongoing, like in "делается много всего", "делаемо" is a virtually non-existent form in modern Russian. Ideally it would be nice to understand phrases like "желаемо но недостижимо" but anyways - in the framework of your question - just don't use this form at all.

Comment: "It is (being) done" : _делается_ (now, usually). "It was being done": _делалось_ (usually earlier, in those times). "It was/has/had been done": _было сделано_  (earlier once, one time).

Comment: Ah, one more: _делалось_ : "it used to be done / it was done (usually), it was being done".

Comment: It is difficult to understand for me too, because some verbs (verb "done" too) in Present Tense is translated sometimes as прошедшее время (and sometimes as настоящее время).

Answer (score 1):

Use the impersonal (subjectless) 3rd-person plural, **делают** (**делали, будут делать, сделают, сделали**). Usually a lot more idiomatic than **делается**, unless you're talking about doing things in theory.

The difference between **сделано** and **было сделано** is, roughly, the difference between "has been done" and "was done".